# SelectBoxIt inputs in a bootsrap form with 100% widths

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using SelectBoxIt inputs (http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/) in Bootstrap 3 horizontal forms. I would like the input to grow and collapse with the width of the form however when setting the widths to 100% they end up collapsing.

I have created a JSFiddle to show my issue and wondered if anyone who is good with CSS can come up with a solution or suggestion?

http://jsfiddle.net/oceanexplorer/a5AZF/

### HTML

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label">Option1</label>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
            <select name="foo">
                <option value="1">Foo1</option>
                <option value="2">Foo2</option>
                <option value="3">Foo3</option>
                <option value="4">Foo4</option>
                <option value="5">Foo5</option>
                <option value="6">Foo with a really, really long text line that we shall use in order to test the wrapping of text within an option or optgroup</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 control-label">Option1</label>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
            <select name="foo">
                <option value="1">Foo1</option>
                <option value="2">Foo2</option>
                <option value="3">Foo3</option>
                <option value="4">Foo4</option>
                <option value="5">Foo5</option>
                <option value="6">Foo with a really, really long text line that we shall use in order to test the wrapping of text within an option or optgroup</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

CSS

```
.selectboxit-container .selectboxit-options,
.selectboxit-container .selectboxit
{
    width: 100%;
}

.col-xs-8,
.col.sm-8,
.col-md-8,
.col-lg-8
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

### Javascript

```
$("select").selectBoxIt({
    autoWidth: false
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include the container in your first rule:

```
.selectboxit-container .selectboxit-options,
.selectboxit-container .selectboxit,
.selectboxit-container {
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a5AZF/3/

Comment: I've accepted this as it did exactly what I wanted...so simple a fix, doh! I now have an issue however that if you select the option that has a long text value, then reduce the window size, at different point the text disappears...any thoughts?